# Flash, Flash Builder, AIR. Three simple questions

Tags: android, flash, air

I have 3 questions to clarify my workflow of AIR apps:

- Can I use Spark components when I'm making a game with Flash CS5?
- Can I import SWC (created in Flash) in my AIR for Android projects when I'm using Flash Builder?
- Can I load a full SWF game (created in Flash) in an AIR for Android app (example: Main menu of the game written in MXML and game in Flash) and run it smoothly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not directly. As you compile inside of the Flash IDE, you don't have the Flex framework included, and as such you have neither the Spark nor the Halo components from the Flex framework. You *could* import the Flex framework within the Flash IDE (by pointing the IDE to the location of the Flex framework) but I'm not totally sure if this will work that easily.

   Nevertheless I believe that doing so would be the wrong way. You should rather work on whatever you need the IDE separately and export the created document as SWC to then import it in a Flex project. You are much more flexible that way and have the Flex framework there where it belongs to, with the more lower levelled object (the ones you created in the IDE) as a simple element within the complex framework.
2. Yes, absolutely. This is the preferred way to use components (as in *objects*) created in the Flash IDE inside of a code based project.
3. As with any Flash content, you are able to dynamically load other SWF files into the running application, yes.

Answer (score 0):

for last two question the asnwer is YES, you can.. and you do the same that you do in Flash.

For the first one, I think yes, but maybe you should reference Spark comps. in Flash... and I don't know about that.